# Passing data to homescreen using async function?

Tags: flutter, dart

What i want to do is basically when the app sends http 200 response,i want to navigate my app by passing the "_user" with it. Here is the code

```
signIn(String email, String password) async {
                     User _user;
                     final http.Response response = await http.post("$SERVER_IP/rest-auth/login/",
                                  body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                                    'email':email,
                                    'password':password,
                                  }),
                                  headers: <String, String>{
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                                    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "**",
                                  },
                                );
                                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                                  var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
                                 _user = User.fromJSON(responseJson['user']);
                                 //This is what i want to do:
                                // HomeScreen(user: _user,)  
                                }
                              else if (response.statusCode == 400) {
                                  error = 'Wrong email or password';
                                  _showError(error);
                                }
                              else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
                                  error = 'Server error';
                                  _showError(error);
                                }
                                else if (response.statusCode == 502) {
                                  error = 'Server error';
                                  _showError(error);
                                }
                                else {
                                  error = 'Application error';
                                  _showError(error);
                                }

                              }
```

How can i do it?

Update:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building FeedScreen(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: FeedScreenState#4ae55):
type '() => void' is not a subtype of type '() => Future<void>'
```

Update 2:

```
class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  const FeedScreen({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  FeedScreenState createState() => FeedScreenState(user: user);
}

class FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  final User user;
  FeedScreenState({Key key, this.posts,this.user});
  final List<Post> posts;
  
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: refreshlist,
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
          future: FetchPosts(http.Client()),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

            return snapshot.hasData ? PostsList(posts: snapshot.data,user:user,postcategoryfeed:postcategoryfeed,limit:limit)
                :
            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.pink,valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.pinkAccent)));

          },
        ),


      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code.I basically put the user and adapt the data for it.
HomeScreen is the same, it runs user through the states and sends it to feed.
Others are functioning fine but when User is needed,i have the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to use `Navigator` to navigate on second page

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
       _user = User.fromJSON(responseJson['user']);
       
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(user: _user,)));
}
```

Comment: `type '() => void' is not a subtype of type '() => Future<void>'`

Comment: @umarbeyoglu please recheck answer

Comment: i still face the same issue

Comment: @umarbeyoglu where you are getting this issue?

Comment: @umarbeyoglu please add your `FeedScreen()` class code snippet

Comment: Looks your right to me not getting why exactly this issue occured

Comment: I am opening this issue under new topic.I will post the link here once i do.

Comment: @umarbeyoglu sure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847515/type-void-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-futurevoid

Comment: Your answer was fine.I solved the problem,issue was from somewhere else.